# Función de comparación de qsort con comportamiento extraño

Tags: c, array, ordenamiento

Estaba escribiendo un programa cuyo objetivo era leer un archivo de texto, ordenar los datos y luego escribirlos en otro archivo.

El problema surgió cuando traté de ordenar el array personasLeidas (el cual contiene las estructuras que estoy utilizando para ordenar los datos). Cuando usé

```
strcmp(otraPersona->region, unaPersona->region)
```

el array se ordenó, pero al revés. Y cuando cambié los parámetros de dicho `strcmp`, me encontré (al debuggear) con un array vacío (por algún motivo `qsort` llenó cada elemento de cada struct en el array con 0's o bien \0's, y no tengo idea de por qué). Les dejo el código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <commons/string.h>
#include <commons/txt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct persona{
    char region[51];
    int edad;
    long dni;
    char nombreYApellido[31];
    long telefono;
    long saldo
} persona;

int criterioOrdenamiento(const void*, const void*);
void mostrarArray(persona* personas);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE* archivo;
    char* nombreArchivo = argv[1];

    int numeroPersonaActual = 0;

    if(archivo = fopen(nombreArchivo, "r")){
        char renglonActual[1000];
        //aguanta hasta 100 personas
        persona* personasLeidas = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct persona));
        char** renglonActualSeparado;
        persona unaPersona;

        while(fgets(renglonActual, 1000, archivo)){

            renglonActualSeparado = string_split(renglonActual, ";");

            char* region = renglonActualSeparado[0];
            char* nombreYApellido = renglonActualSeparado[1];
            int edad = atoi(renglonActualSeparado[2]);
            long telefono = atol(renglonActualSeparado[3]);
            long dni = atol(renglonActualSeparado[4]);
            long saldo = atol(renglonActualSeparado[5]);


            strcpy(unaPersona.region, region);
            strcpy(unaPersona.nombreYApellido, nombreYApellido);
            unaPersona.edad = edad;
            unaPersona.telefono = telefono;
            unaPersona.dni = dni;
            unaPersona.saldo = saldo;


            if (edad > 18){
                personasLeidas[numeroPersonaActual] = unaPersona;
            }

            numeroPersonaActual++;
        }

        mostrarArray(personasLeidas);
        printf("\n\n\n");

        //filtrar y ordenar el array
        qsort(personasLeidas, 100, sizeof(struct persona), criterioOrdenamiento);

        mostrarArray(personasLeidas);

        //guardar en archivo


        free(personasLeidas);
        fclose(archivo);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    return -2;
}

int criterioOrdenamiento(const void* personaA, const void* personaB){

    persona * unaPersona = personaA;
    persona * otraPersona = personaB;

    //faltaria comparar por edad
    return strcmp(otraPersona->region, unaPersona->region);
}

void mostrarArray(persona* personas){
    int contador = 0;
    while(personas[contador].dni){
        printf("%s\n", personas[contador].region);
        contador++;
    }
}
```

Acá dejo el contenido del archivo de texto que estoy usando para probar el código.

```
CASA;UnNombre;20;11213657;10000000;150
ARFE;Lucrecia;22;11487100;10000001;100
TEST;PEPE;21;11000000;10000002;120
NONI;pocho;29;12345678;10000003;900
ARLEK;test;30;10000000;10000004;1000
```

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en inglés. **El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.**

Comment: ya ayudé a traducirla solo esperar se apruebe dicha acción @Jorgesys

Comment: me atreví a traducirla por que dentro del código que compartió hay palabras en español, por lo cual se pudiera inferir que si sabe español

Comment: Mil perdones por el error en el posteo en inglés, hace mucho no posteaba y la última vez que lo había hecho había sido en el otro foro. Perdón, ya está en español!

Comment: @Nato Tambien debes traducir el título

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, fíjate que si una persona no es mayor de edad va a dejar un hueco en el array:

```
if (edad > 18){
  personasLeidas[numeroPersonaActual] = unaPersona;
}
numeroPersonaActual++;
```

Si quieres evitar huecos, no incrementes el índice salvo que se añadan elementos en la lista:

```
if (edad > 18){
  personasLeidas[numeroPersonaActual] = unaPersona;
  numeroPersonaActual++;
}
```

Por otro lado, la llamada a `qsort` es incorrecta:

```
qsort(personasLeidas, 100, sizeof(struct persona), criterioOrdenamiento);
//                    ^^^
```

No tienes que pasarle toda la memoria del array sino únicamente las posiciones ocupadas. ¿cómo esperas que `qsort` decida que ahora sí debe ignorar esos huecos pero que debe tratarlos en tu próximo proyecto? No puede...

Lo dicho, la llamada debería quedar mas bien así:

```
qsort(personasLeidas, numeroPersonaActual, sizeof(struct persona), criterioOrdenamiento);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Esos tips resolvieron el problema!!